# In this context which is better: astuta or intelligente?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which word is better in Italian in the context "Smart Cleaning"?

If both are ok, may we use "Pulizia astuta"?

Thank you in advance,
Tanya

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!!

Comment: Some people would probably use “smart” in Italian too (thinking about smartphones and the like), but I'd go with _intelligente_ as in the answers.

Comment: Which context? You didn't really write much about the use of this expression

Answer (score 8):

Use

> Pulizia intelligente

This is how we translate smart in the context of tech.

"Astuta" is for a person or animal, it is the classical attribute of a fox and I think that it would translate to "clever" (I'm no native English speaker though)

Comment: I'd translate "astuto" with "clever" or "cunning" maybe

Answer (score 2):

In this context I would go for "Pulizia intelligente", since intelligente is more general and polyhedral.

**Astuta** is more like **furba** generally referred to the proverbial fox or a particular clever person.